# Assembly(dll) Update Changes Takes too much time for windows

Tags: asp.net, .net, dll, .net-assembly, gac

One Web Based project have class library,means dll file generate at back end while build my created project

**Tried solution 1:**
I copied that Dll into **"C:\Windows\assembly"** folder and register through
"regasm.exe C:\DLLName.dll /tlb:TLBName.tlb"

it's register successfully but,Update site takes too many times, suppose I register dll today then I can find my changes tomorrow

**Tried solution 2:**

I copied that Dll file and paste in to my server's **C:\Windows\System32** folder and register through gacutil -i command from CMD

but it's not worked for me,means can't see changes in site

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Tricks is uninstall Dll by **regasm /u**  command and again register it find updated version

But Register DLL not find In C:/Windows/Assembly folder why? I don't know..